# R : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create grouped stacked bar chart using R. and successfully i achieved too. but finally the code breaks my heart. please anyone help me to solve my issue.

This is expected one. It is working fine if data set contains less data.

[image]

My R code :

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
library(ggplot2)
d<-dataset
melted = melt(dataset)
ggplot(melted, aes(x =YYYY_MMM,y=d$BVM)) +
geom_col(aes(fill =ID),na.rm=TRUE,position ="stack") +
facet_grid( IN_OUT~. + TCODE ~.,switch="both") +
geom_text(aes( label = round(d$BVM,digits=2), group = ID),position =position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="D",ncol=25)) + 
theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
theme(legend.position="bottom")  +
theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))  +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'))
```

Problem :
The code provide needed result while running sample data set. Once move with original data it through error(" Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (681): x, y, fill, tooltip
Execution halted"

Comment: Of note: most text and code editors do not charge for indentation and basic formatting features. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help documentation, and [what can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Remember, you also need to [include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described. When done, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Comment: Please remove all the irrelevant code. Also look at the message, what are the lengths of the two variables in your aes()?

Comment: Replace `d$BVM` with a variable of `melted`